# mongo $where returning everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find the documents in the database between specifit date ranges.

```
 var event = {
            to : 1393454361,
            from : 1393354361
};
```

I have `event.from` and `event.to` as unix time integers and am using this to try and only return events, that are between the two date ranges:

```
db.events.find({
  "event": "test",
  "message.tableid": 123,
  $where: function () { 
    return ( 
      (event.from - this._id.getTimestamp()) > (event.from - event.to) 
    )  
  }
}).sort(
  { "message.time": -1 }
).forEach(function(error, x) {
  if (error || !x) {
    console.log("error getting items");
    console.log("Current HPH in this range:");
    console.log(hph);
  } else {
    console.log(
      "Calc: ", 
      (event.from - x._id.getTimestamp() > (event.from - event.to))
    );
    if (event.from - x._id.getTimestamp() > (event.from - event.to)) {
      hph = hph + 1;
    }
  }
})
```

For some reason, if I use an `if` to check whether the date is between the ranges, it works.
But when I move my statement to the `$where`-clause, `all` documents get returned.

I just a bunch of documents in the collection that look like so:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("530cd8d610d28ebc27951eb8"),
"event" : "test",
"message" : {
    "tableid" : 123
}
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("530cd8d610d28ebc27952fb8"),
"event" : "test",
"message" : {
    "tableid" : 123
}
}
```

Any ideas>?

If I try and use this as the `$where` to check for the last 24 hours it works fine:

```
 $where: function () {
     return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  
 }
```

Comment: maybe you can add some of your documents to the question so people can visualise what you are trying to do. A useful edit.

Comment: thanks, just added a sample

Comment: What are "event.from" and "event.to"? We can't see this.

Comment: event.from and event.to are just simple intergers that hold the unix time value.

Comment: In the question please. Exactly what you are doing. It's important in order to get an answer.

Comment: Dude. If not obvious, what are the values of `event.from` and `event.to`? We need the values, not a statement that you are using the vars.

Comment: its just a unix time,from : 1393454361, to : 1393354361 is an example

Comment: So before I answer, why is your `to` value less than your `from`?

Comment: It isn't, it was a typo, ,to : 1393454361, from : 1393354361. Im just confused as to why it would work in the if statment and not in there $where

Comment: I think you should edit that in the question, but what you are saying is, you want to check if the difference between the ( `from` - `ObjectId.timestamp()` ) is greater than your ( `from` - `to` ). So basically is the objectId time greater than your `to` time. Logically speaking. See the hoop jumping here?

Comment: If I run this: db.events.find({ $where: function () { return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  }  })
in the console I get back all the documents from the past day. When I try running it in node js it does not work that is my only difficulty, the logic works in the if statement just not in the db.events.find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing valid JSON. The *mongo shell* is **very** forgiving, other things are not.

```
 db.events.find({ 
     "$where": 
         "function () {
             return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) 
         }" 
  }, function(err, result) {

    // test err and process result

  });
```

Since it's not valid, the condition means nothing. Equivalent to `{}` in the `.find()`.

Also, Try and re-factor to **not** use [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). You just threw away your index usage and forced a full table scan.

And as mentioned in comments, your long routing logic that can be simplified.

Comment: use a string to contain your function code and don't access anything declared outside the function - because this function will be running in mongodb environment, it cannot see other parts of your code. but still you can use mongodb's print function for debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an if statement or a where clause try using the $gte and $lt operators in the query. 
Read this article:
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Comment: True. But you did not really answer the question, did you.